# Jquery catching click event on jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i have been trying to figure this out lately but i can't

the problem is that i have an `input` field with type `text` that i need to get the current input data when the values from the autocomplete are selected. *Note i am using jQuery UI autocomplete.*

i can catch the `keyup` event but when a user uses clicks on the autocomplete values. jQuery does not fire the `change` event handler, i tried using every event handler there is but to no avail.

i think it cannot catch a DOM based manipulation of an element? i'm not sure. here is a 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qTLGc/2/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Like this** http://jsfiddle.net/PUpRr/

`select` options should do the trick.

*Options/events/methods API documentation* : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Hope this fits the needs `:)`

**Sample code**

```
$("#to").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        var friendsArray = [];
        friendsArray = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "hulk",
            "value": "hulk"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ironman",
            "value": "ironman"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Foobar",
            "value": "Foobar"
        }];

        response(friendsArray);
        return;


    },

    select: function (e, ui) {

        alert("selected!");
    },

    change: function (e, ui) {

        alert("changed!");
    }
});
```

Comment: well that was fast, should have read the manual though, any way thanks this is what i need.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome had issues retaining the ui for clicked changes, so I added a mousedown handler for the individual popup list anchor tags in the autocomplete open: event.  It's also a good place for styling the list:

```
    function onItemTypeAheadListOpen(e, ui) {
       // Stub for list click issues
       $('.ui-autocomplete a').mousedown(function () {
         lastItemClicked = this.innerText;
       });
       // Override default list style
       $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', '600');
       $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '480px');
    }
```